# msiexec commandline incorrect

Tags: windows-installer

I want to install an application(FEKO) using the .msi file, and cant use the easier .exe installer. I am trying to installing it using the following command on cmd

```
C:\Feko_Installer>msiexec /i "C:\Feko_Installer\feko_distrib_x.y_win64.msi" /qb- /FEKO_TMPDIR="C:\Temp" /FEKO_SILENT="1" /ADDLOCAL="Default" /TARGET_IS_EM64T="1" /INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\FEKO\6.2"
```

When I try to execute this command I get the Windows Installer "usage" dialog window. Is there any thing I am doing wrong?

Comment: See link below for a command line builder tool that may help in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments require / ( /I  /QB )  Properties (FEKO_SILENT=)  should not have a /.

[Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Christopher has given the right idea.
After I haven't understood his sentence reading it the first time, here more clear and comprehensive:

- Don't prefix MSI properties with a slash generally, neither your own, nor the builtin !
- The used properties in your commandline are:

FEKO_TMPDIR
FEKO_SILENT
ADDLOCAL
TARGET_IS_EM64T
INSTALLDIR

Just let the "/" away for them.
BTW, I would add a /L*v "c:\mylogfile.log" kinda parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To help eliminate msiexec.exe command line errors, try the Wise Command Line Builder Tool:
https://serverfault.com/questions/30068/silent-install-of-msi/67001#67001

[image]